# realsense depthimage to laserscan

Tags: ros, 2dlaserscan, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I recently got a realsense R200 sensor. I was able to follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense) and able to get data from the realsense. But I want to get laserscan data from the realsense. So I followed this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan).

This is the command I used to convert depthimage to laserscan

> rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan
> depthimage_to_laserscan
> image:=/camera/depth/image_raw
> camera_info:/camera/depth/camera_info

I am able to see the scan data, but there are way too many NaN values in the data. I tried to figure out why it was happening, but I was not able to. Can someone please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270058/realsense-depthimage-to-laserscan/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-01**:
When I used the RealSense R200 I also had many `NaN` values. Same thing with two different boards and different R200's, although one of the boards was better than the other.

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2017-09-01**:
How did you solve it? @jayess

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-01**:
We went with the board (TK1?) that gave us less `NaN` values. So, we didn't really solve it, but accepted it.

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2017-09-01**:
oh wow! I thought it was the problem with the depthto_laserscan code I am using. Thanks.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-01**:
I can't say for sure what the problem is or isn't. Just be aware that it may be something less obvious like what I mentioned.

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2017-09-01**:
when you guys moved to TK1, are you still using depthto_laserscan node to get the scan data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan this thing says under published topics that there may be NaN values.

---

Originally posted by [srnand](https://answers.ros.org/users/34391/srnand/) with karma: 31 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0